# Is it possible to save a Key type in Settings.settings?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using Settings.settings in my application to save variables after the program is closed.I want to store Keys of `Windows.Input.Key` type.

Unfortunately I cannot find the type available:
[image]

Code that doesn't work:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.F3_User = Key.F3;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to edit the settings file by hand.
To do this, right click on the settings file and chose "open with" -> Xml (text) editor.
Here, you change the Type to System.Windows.Input.Key:

```
<Setting Name="F3_User" Type="System.Windows.Input.Key" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)"></Value>
</Setting>
```

After this, everything should work as expected.